# Debugging an SSL WebSocket that isn't running in a browser

Tags: ssl, websocket, proxy

I am trying to view the messages and communication of an SSL WebSocket server and client. The client is written in Java, so I could technically view the code with something like [Recaf](https://www.coley.software/Recaf/) or [JD-GUI](http://java-decompiler.github.io/), but I do not have access to the WS server. Is there any program that I could use to intercept the traffic of the client and server (Note: I am able to change the host, port, and protocol of the client's WS connection (like change it to `ws://localhost:8080` from `wss://server:port/path`)).

Is there any program that can act as a non SSL WebSocket server, and then forward all connections to the remote server while logging the messages?

Comment: mitmproxy should be able to handle websocket. Wireshark can also be used to sniff traffic and display websocket data.

Comment: I have looked at mitmproxy, but I am not very familiar with the software. I'm sure there is a way, but I haven't found it yet. As for Wireshark, I have used that, but I am talking about an SSL WebSocket which is encrypted so I cannot see the message data.